# Ng-repeat list isn't updating

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a Controler1 that sends an event on button click:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('Click');
```

Then I'm catching this event in Controller2 and updating a list of orders:

```
$scope.$on('Click', function() {
    console.log("Somebody clicked the button");
    $scope.showingOrders = Order.getMyOrders();
});
```

where Order.getMyOrders() sends a request to server for a list of orders.

Controller2 controls this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#/dashboard" id="{{order.id}}" 
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#showOrderModal"
        class="list-group-item"
        ng-click="setClickedOrder(showingOrders[$index])"
        ng-repeat="order in showingOrders | orderBy : '-id'">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
           Order №{{order.id}} from {{order.owner.fullName}}
        </h4>
        p class="list-group-item-text">{{order.description}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

What am I getting:

- By the first click "Somebody clicked the button" is showing in
  console, but the list of orders is not redrawing
- By the next clicks an
  order list redraws, but always the last order isn't showing

The code for Order.getMyOrders():

```
app.factory('Order', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource(BASE_PATH + ORDER_PATH, {}, {
        get: {url: BASE_PATH + ORDER_PATH + '/:orderId', method: 'GET', params: {orderId: '@orderId'}},
        create: {method: 'POST'},
        getNearMe: {url: BASE_PATH + ORDER_PATH + '/near', method: 'GET',
            params: {latitude: '', longitude: ''}, isArray: true},
        getDoneOrders: {url: BASE_PATH + ORDER_PATH + '/done', method: 'GET',
            params: {latitude: '', longitude: ''}},
        getMyOrders: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can I do this in another way?

Comment: show code for `Order.getMyOrders()`. Should be setting scope variable inside the callback

Comment: Added the code for it, but I don't think that the problem is there.